# How to debug "wlan_wake kernel wakelock" on an unrooted device?

Tags: battery-life, kernel, wakelock

The question is as short as the title. I've a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 & it has started showing issues where the CPU remains in lowest possible frequency (250Mhz) and it doesn't go to deep sleep.

I tried uninstalling all the apps that I installed in last 2 days but I can still see the issues.

Searching on google isn't helping either. Most of the posts that get in search results are the posts where people paste the betterbatterstats output. On the official wiki, https://github.com/asksven/BetterBatteryStats-Knowledge-Base/wiki/wlan_wake , it's mentioned that a sniffer should be used to debug.

I saw that most of the sniffers actually require root. So, how do I debug this wakelock without rooting my phone?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused by "scanning always available" under Advanced Wifi Options.
Disable it and you shall see this reduced significantly.